# How to name a csv file after overwriting in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, csv, pyspark, databricks

I am using Databricks notebook to read and write the file into the same location. But when I write into the file I am getting a lot of files with different names.
Like this:

[image]

I am not sure why these files are created in the location I specified.
Also, another file with the name "new_location" was created after I performed the write operation

[image]

What I want is that after reading the file from Azure Blob Storage I should write the file into the same location with the same name as the original into the same location. But I am unable to do so. please help me out as I am new to Pyspark
I have already mounted and now I am reading the CSV file store in an azure blob storage container.
The overwritten file is created with the name "part-00000-tid-84371752119947096-333f1e37-6fdc-40d0-97f5-78cee0b108cf-31-1-c000.csv"

Code:

```
df = spark.read.csv("/mnt/ndemo/nsalman/addresses.csv", inferSchema = True)
df = df.toDF("firstName","lastName","street","town","city","code")
df.show()
file_location_new = "/mnt/ndemo/nsalman/new_location"
# write the dataframe as a single file to blob storage
df.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \
  .mode('overwrite').option("header", "true").save(file_location_new)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark will save a partial csv file for each partition of your dataset. To generate a single csv file, you can convert it to  a pandas dataframe, and then write it out.

Try to change these lines:

```
df.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \
  .mode('overwrite').option("header", "true").save(file_location_new)
```

to this line

```
df.toPandas().to_csv(file_location_new, header=True)
```

You might need to prepend `"/dbfs/"` to `file_location_new` for this to work.

Here is a minimal self-contained example that demonstrate how to write a csv file with pandas:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)], ["Testing", "123"])
df.show()
df.toPandas().to_csv("/dbfs/" + "/mnt/ndemo/nsalman/" + "testfile.csv", header=True)
```

Comment: file_location_new = "/mnt/ndemo/nsalman/new_location"
# convert it to a pandas dataframe, and then write it out
df = df.toPandas().to_csv("/dbfs/"+file_location_new, header=True)
df.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \
  .mode('overwrite').option("header", "true").save(file_location_new)

I did this, but it's giving me error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'toPandas'

Comment: Are you sure df is a spark dataframe? I have updated my answer to be more precise on what lines to change.